# generic interface with bounded generic interface

Tags: java, generics

Say I have generics interface :

```
public interface MyContainer<E>{
     E someMethod();
}
```

Now I have another interface that I want it to be something like this:

```
public interface MyService<T extends MyContainer<E>>{
     // someMethod goes here   
}
```

It doesn't compile of course, it only compiles like this :

```
public interface MyService<E,T extends MyContainer<E>>{
     // someMethod goes here   
}
```

but I don't like it since MyService interface doesn't care about E it only cares that its type parameter extends MyContainer. Any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: What do you do with T? Unless you know the type of `E`, you have to use ?, Then all you can do is use it to produce Objects (or lists of Object, etc).

Comment: Does this fit your solution? `public interface MyService<T extends MyContainer<?>>{}`
It _does_ compile, and if  you truly don't care about `E`, then `?` should be sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but I don't like it

Start liking it.

You must declare type parameters before referencing them, just as you would declare variables before using them.

If you care about the type of `E`, then you must declare it.  The interface `MyService` does care about `E` if it's referencing it with `T extends MyContainer<E>`.

If your interface doesn't care about what `E` is at all, then you could use an unbounded wildcard.

```
public interface MyService<T extends MyContainer<?>>
```

However, every implementation of this interface would need to either redeclare `T` exactly like this or supply a type argument that satisfies this constraint exactly.  You wouldn't be able to get rid of that `?`.

Your declaring `E` and using it as you are is the best solution I can see.  Having to type an extra `E,` is no big problem.

Comment: "You wouldn't be able to get rid of that ?" I would say even that at the end you don't want as concrete classes would probably use the generic type specified in `MyContainer` by implementing :  `MyService<T extends MyContainer<Foo>>`. Or else it makes no sense to make `MyContainer` a generic class.